# Extendable wxSizer depending on window size

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to make a layout which is containing some buttons and panels using wxWidgets. The issue is that I can't create an extendable wxSizer on the center of the other frames.

I tried using some of the wxWidgets components like wxBoxSizer,wxFlexGridSizer, and more. Is there any good advice for implementing this layout?

The simple representation of the window is like that: [image]

Comment: could you show some code of what you tried? Did you use any RAD tool, such as wxSmith, wxGlade, etc? It is very easy to create `ANY` layout with such a tool...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at this as multiple nested blocks.

1. At the highest level, you have 3 blocks ordered *horizontally*: right rectangle, center rectangle, and left rectangle.  In order to accomplish this you need a `wxBoxSizer` with horizontal orientation.
2. At the second level, the center rectangle, you have 3 blocks ordered *vertically*: the top rectangle, the center rectangle, and the bottom rectangle.  You will need a `wxBoxSizer` with vertical orientation.
3. In order to get the center to expand to fill the space, you will need to use the `proportion` parameter.

Here is a code snippet example:

```
wxBoxSizer* rootsizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

//TODO: the right side control is whatever you need it to be
wxPanel* rightPanel = new wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, rightPanelSize);
//NOTE the use of 0 as the proportion; this means the right panel will NOT expand
//horizontally; it is fixed in size.  The wxEXPAND flag means it will expand vertically
//to fill
rootsizer->Add(rightpanel, 0, wxEXPAND, 0);

//Our center sizer to contain our center controls
wxBoxSizer* centersizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
//NOTE the use of 1 as the proportion; this means the center panel will expand HORIZONTALLY to fill all available space
rootsizer->Add(centersizer, 1, wxEXPAND, 0);

//TODO: whatever control goes on the left
wxPanel* leftpanel = new wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, leftPanelSize);
//Proportion is again 0 to prevent expanding horizontally
rootsizer->Add(leftpanel, 0, wxEXPAND, 0);

//Now the second level

//TODO: whatever control goes on the top
wxPanel* toppanel = new wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, topPanelSize);
//Proportion is 0 to prevent expanding VERTICALLY (because we are now in the center sizer
//which is a vertical sizer
centersizer->Add(toppanel, 0, wxEXPAND, 0);

//Our final depth, the centermost control, is set to a proportion of 1 to fill the space
//vertically
//TODO: whatever is your center control
wxPanel* centerpanel = new wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
centersizer->Add(centerpanel, 1, wxEXPAND, 0);

//And then the bottom control at proportion 0
wxPanel* bottompanel= new wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, bottomPanelSize);
centersizer->Add(bottompanel, 0, wxEXPAND, 0);
```

By combining multiple levels of sizers, along with `wxEXPAND` and properly assigning `proportion`, you can get the right flexibility.  You just have to learn to look at it in terms of groups of controls that expand and contract in just one direction.